# local and statement modifiers (e.g. postfix if)

Tags: perl

[`perlsyn`, "Statement-Modifiers" section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) clearly states that

> The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` modified with a statement
>   modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x if ...` ) is
>   undefined.

Unfortunately this list is missing `local` and [its own documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) doesn't cover its behavior either. I assume it is undefined as well and docs are just incomplete in those particular sections.

Is this actually covered in docs anywhere?

Comment: `local` doesn't create a variables, much less a lexical one. (It backs up variables to be restored later.) And no, conditionally executing `local`, as odd as it looks, doesn't cause problems.

Comment: In reality, the problem is using a lexical var declared with without first executing the declaration. `my $x if f();` is explicitly called out, but the real trouble is `my $x if f(); ... $x ...`, and `f() and my $x; ... $x ...` is just as bad.

Comment: Note that `my $x if 0` works the same as `state $x`, but that is purely accidental and shouldn't be relied upon.

Answer (score 14):

The undefined behavior of using a statement modifier on `my` & Co., such as

```
my $x = 1  if $flag;  # UNDEFINED behavior
```

is due to the fact that the `my $x` declaration happens at compile time while the `= 1` assignment happens at runtime, as does the test. Thus the statement as a whole is broken (is it supposed to not even assign at all?), and the behavior of this line of code is considered undefined.

However, `local` is very different. From [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local()) (my emphasis)

> A `local` **modifies** its listed variables to be "local" to the enclosing block, `eval`, or `do` FILE --and to any subroutine called from within that block. A local just gives temporary values to **global** (meaning package) variables. It **does not create** a local variable.

Thus `local` does something completely different than `my` or `our`; it saves the value of its target (global) variable for the rest of the block and restores it on exit from the block.

Also, since [`local` is a run-time operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local()) there are no compilation-vs-runtime issues of declare + assign, as in `my $x = 1`, so a postfix condition can be used. Consider

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $flag = shift // 1;

our $var = 1;

{
    local $var if $flag;
    $var = 2;
    say $var;
}

say $var;
```

When run with `$flag` set (`script.pl`) the `local`-ization happens and the last print shows that the global `our $var` has been preserved. With flag unset (`script.pl 0`) this doesn't happen, the value of the global is not saved away for the block, and ends up overwritten.

With `local $var = 2 if $flag;` neither the localization nor the assignment happens.

If only the `local` statement itself is conditioned that must be done in the postfix manner since the effect of `local` lasts only within the enclosing scope (so `if ($f) { local $v }` does nothing for the rest of the code).

Doing this may change the code behavior radically, and possibly at a high level, based on a mere value of a single condition; I'd recommend to thread carefully with such code. This short program in particular only shows how a postfix condition *can* be used.  Thanks to [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth)  and [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments.

Comment: using local with postfix if is fairly common; in fact you cannot use local in a regular if statement because the local is undone at the end of the if block.

Comment: @ysth Thanks ... but such use is fine only in very specific circumstances, right?  I'd still recommend against that in general. I'll adjust the (overly-strong) statements, thank you

Comment: yes, a conditional local is pretty specific and rare, but this is the way to do it

Comment: `local $foo = $bar if $x;` is basically an efficient way of writing `local $foo = $x ? $bar : $foo;`

Comment: @ikegami It's a nice capability -- I am just itchy with localizing-or-not a variable. In a tight and clearly segregated segment, sure, but in general it spooks me. It can change things at large scope, given that it is about globals. Just wouldn't want this page to serve as an ad for that.

Comment: I don't like the look of it, but `local $foo` simply pushes an instruction on the stack that causes `$foo = $saved_value;` to happen on stack unwind. Since it just pushes on the stack, there's no reason it can't be done conditionally. Just adding some clarification to previous comments, not recommending any changes to the answer.

Comment: Re "*Also, since local is a run-time operator the compilation-vs-runtime issues are not involved and a condition can be used. Consider*", It's `my`'s run-time effect that causes the problem, so saying that `local` has no problems because it's a run-time effect makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami I see the problem with `my $x=1 if $f` to be in that the declaration(compilation)+assignment(runtime) combo gets torn up by a runtime test, so to speak.  I meant to say that since a statement with `local` is all runtime it's free of that problem.  But it doesn't read right, thank you; I'll edit.

Comment: @ikegami re: efficient way, so localizing (and implied restoring) happens regardless of `if` or what? Both your examples retain `local`.

Comment: `our` does not creates anything either. Why `local` is different from it?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov (1) Re: "_happens regardless of `if` or what?_" -- no, it doesn't; whether it happens depends on the `if` test.  Run the code in my answer: when `$flag` is false the `$var` _is not_ localized.   (2) `our` is indeed a bit different, being global, but it is in many ways "close" to `my`.  It sure creates something -- you can introduce a variable (name) with it, just like with `my`. The `local` works only on the existing ones (under `strict`), and can be conditioned just fine.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov, Re "*`our` does not creates anything either*", `our` creates a lexical var just like `my`. More specifically, `our $x;` means `\my $x = \$CURRENT_PACKAGE::x;` (with `CURRENT_PACKAGE` replaced with the actual package name).

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Try this: `perl -Mstrict -wE'BEGIN { say "B1" }; our $v; BEGIN { say $v // "undef", ", B2" }; say $v=2;`.  There is no problem with using `$v` in the second `BEGIN`, while if you move `our $v` declaration after the second block this won't compile (since `$v` is an unknown symbol in the second `BEGIN` block).  This means that `our $v;` goes at compile time.  _[This corrects a sentence in the text in my previous comment, now removed, which referred to my earlier, different, test and mismatched the code]_